# Why are the lights and fans in my home flickering and varying in speed?

Tags: electrical

I have very weird electrical behavior in my house. Fans will suddenly slow them speed up. Lights flicker randomly for for random times. 2-10 seconds. Everything in my home is wired with 12-3 wiring. Could different currents interfere across circuits?[image]

Comment: Doubtful. Have you contacted your power provider?

Comment: No. Not yet, what would they do to test the system?

Comment: Test each breaker on AC voltage, you should have 120 volts on each leg, then go to the source of the flicker and test the wires going in, to make sure their reading right around 120 volts as well, requires turning the breakers on and off and on and off and on lol I see rust on 3 of your breakers so I'm thinking maybe a breaker is starting to go since it's multiple things, the things that are flicking, are they all on the same breaker ?

Comment: Can you measure voltages on each leg of the faulty circuit?

Answer (score 3):

Boy, that installer just loved his **multi-wire branch circuits**.  That's fine; I think they're awesome and my CH panels are full of them too.  However, there are rules you must follow in any MWBC installation.

The #1 thing you must watch closely is neutrals.   On a normal circuit, a neutral problem just shuts off the circuit.  But on a MWBC, it creates a "lost neutral" situation where the two half-circuit voltages are higher and lower than 120V,  but *add up* to 240V. The high side can fry equipment and start fires, and the voltage will teeter-totter depending on the load on each leg.  So as, say, a freezer starts up, it will wibble-wobble the voltage on the other leg (and its own leg).

I would normally blame backstab connections.  However, one of the rules of MWBCs is that **neutrals must be pigtailed** anywhere both hot legs are present.  You can't use a piece of equipment as the neutral path (as one normally does with receptacles in plain circuits).  So no backstabs should be involved.

Now, if the whole house is doing this, it may have nothing to do with the MWBCs, it may be the same problem - a lost neutral - at the whole-house level.  If so, ***this is an emergency -- call the power company and report an outage*** because most likely, the problem is at the pole or service drop, and that's their bailiwick and they'll fix it for free.   You can also check this by measuring voltage between the main breaker lugs and neutral.  If it is lopsided and gets more lopsided when you turn loads on, that's it!

Now another rule I see your installer did not follow is that whatever means of maintenance shutoff is used, it must shut off both legs of the MWBC.  Here, you use breakers, so the breakers need **handle ties** between them ($3, but hard to find) or change the 2 breakers to a 2-pole breaker.  That is to protect workers,  but it has a side effect: it **makes sure** both legs are on opposite poles.  In fact, for each of the cables, follow the red and black back to the breakers to make sure they are on opposite poles (occupying the same 2 spaces that a 2-pole breaker would use).

If both wires were on the same pole, current from both sub-circuits would stack on the neutral wire, overloading it.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I would recommend you have a professional electrician look at the house.  It sounds like you have a high resistance connection somewhere in the main service connections.  Good Luck.

Comment: After reviewing some more material online. I found that my flickering lights in the living room share a common neutral with the garage. The entire house is a 3 wire system. The flickering got worse when plugged in our deep freeze in the garage. Could this be the problem? The bulbs are LED and I’ve already swapped the switch to one that is specifically for LED.